# Run function in current element by get short code inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

In stead of adding an ID (IdAddMore) to run script inside ID(widget1) like that :

```
<div class="widget" id="widget1">
    <div class="content">
          <div id="IdAddMore"></div>
          <script type='text/javascript'>
          $("#IdAddMore").selectme({
           Numpost:3,
           Postyle : "Enter your style",
           });
          </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

*(widget is added automatically when I add more new widget, It means I can have widget3, widget10, ....Index(3,10..) is any and is not sorted.)*

Widget is a HTML/JS widget.

I want run `selectme` by short code instead of repeating script in each widget.

```
<div class="widget" id="widget1">
    <div class="content">
        [3][mystyle]
    </div>
</div>
<div class="widget" id="widget50">
    <div class="content">
       [4][yourstyle]
    </div>
</div>
...........
```

How can I write only script to catch short code in current element is added :

I write script below but it does not work. Check for me, thanks your help.

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
var getdata = document.getElementsByClassName(".content").innerText || document.getElementById(".content").textContent;
var thevalue = [];
getdata.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, function(g0,g1){thevalue.push(g1);});

$(".widget").selectme({
Numpost:thevalue[0],
Postyle: ""+thevalue[1]+"",
});
</script>
```

Comment: Without more code I can't understand what you are attempting here.  Also, would be useful to know what library this was from (can post to JSFiddle if needed).

Comment: @Deryck: just as nnnnnn's answers. no need catch new event or handler as ajax..because browser is refreshed after widget is added. thanks for your care to my ques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".content").innerText
```

...won't work because `getElementsByClassName()` returns a list, and the list has no `.innerText` property. You'd need to loop over each item.

```
document.getElementById(".content")
```

...won't work because you're passing a class selector rather than a plain id.

Since you're using jQuery, try something like this instead:

```
$(".content").each(function() {
    var content = $(this).text(),
        values = content.match(/\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)\]/);

    $(this).closest(".widget").selectme({
       Numpost:values[1],
       Postyle: values[2],
    });
});
```

Having said that, in my opinion it would be both neater and easier to retrieve values in your markup from script if you uses html5 `data-` attributes, perhaps something like this:

```
<div class="widget" data-numpost="3" data-style="Enter your style">
```

...because then the required jQuery is trivial:

```
$(".widget").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.selectme({
       Numpost : $this.attr("data-numpost"),
       Postyle : $this.attr("data-style")
    });
});
```

If that's not shorthand enough you could say:

```
<div class="widget" data-sm="[3][Enter your style]">
```

...and modify the JS to suit.

Comment: Sorry. I cannot add manually like yours (actually, it is fixed). my friend have also the same answer as you, but it not what i want. Thanks for your suggestion. Can you change your answer as my intention? Thank !

Comment: I highly appreciate your suggestion about adding "data-" and help me for fixing the error. Thank you so much.

Comment: Still trying to figure out the actual purpose/end goal of this question but from what I can gather from his code there's a library making these widgets and he'll need a new event and handler made for the creation of each one.

Comment: @Deryck: your right. Actually, I am not good at all. So I need help for my issue, also help me to learn more.

Comment: @nnnnnn : sorry, brackets may not be removed with your code. I get the error like : %5Bmystyle%5D

Comment: Sorry, I forgot how `.match()` handles the `g` flag. Answer updated to get the values `3` and `Enter your style` without the square bracket.

Comment: @Deryck - My interpretation is that a single block of JS should find all elements of a certain class and process their `[3][style]` content as input into the `.selectme()` plugin (whatever that is).